# Reference request: normal trace and the conormal derivative associated to the operator $Div (A \nabla)$ for a symmetric positive definite $A$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, differential-operators, integral-operators

Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ symmetric positive definite matrix. I am looking for a reference where I could find in which sense the normal trace $\gamma$ and conormal derivative $\gamma_n$  associated to the operator $\operatorname{Div} (A \nabla)$ are defined.
The formal expression of the two above boundary operators are:
$$
\gamma : u\mapsto n\cdot (A u_{\Gamma}),\;\gamma_n: u\mapsto n\cdot (A\nabla u_{\Gamma}),
$$
where $u_{\Gamma}$ denote the restriction of a vector-valued function $u$ at a boundary $\Gamma$.